# Предназначение проверок первых сообщений и запоздалых ответов

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

2 варианта, как тут устроена система проверок, в «Справке» ответа не нашёл:

1. Подобно механизму [патрулирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в Википедии. Сообщения должны проверяться на наличие спама, оскорблений, соответствие тематики Stack Overflow, быть на русском языке; ответы должны являться ответами, а не чем-либо ещё, и т. п. — то есть на явные несоответствия правилам сайта, при которых сообщению грозит удаление, + желательно оформление кода и исправление грамматических/орфографических/пунктуационных ошибок. При этом проверяющий может не разбираться в тематике и не видеть, возможно, очевидных для специалистов ошибок.
2. Более жёсткий. Проверяющий должен знать тему и исправлять очевидные для него, но не различимые на взгляд неспециалиста критические ошибки.

К чему ближе механизм проверок на русскоязычном Stack Overflow? Конечно, желательно, разбираться в вопросе, но так бывает далеко не всегда. Что делать, если не ориентируешься в тематике, но ничего из того, что мной перечислено в п.1, в сообщении новичков/запоздалом ответе нет, — пропускать или принимать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот разделы справки о проверках:

- (500 реп.) [Запоздалые ответы и первые сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

  - Запоздалые ответы чаще прочих оказываются спамом. Особенно привлекают спам вопросы про хостинг и рассылку электропочты (т.е. спама). Также нередко ответ на старый вопрос на самом деле является новым вопросом. В таком случае нужно указать автору на то, что вопрос нужно повторно опубликовать как вопрос. Там даже есть шаблонный комментарий для этого.
  - Первые сообщения подвержены нескольким характерным ошибкам:

    - Вопросы часто не содержат всей необходимой информации или бывают не по теме сайта. В таком случае помогите автору понять, какой информации не хватает или как переформулировать вопрос.
    - Новые участники часто задают в ответах уточняющие вопросы, которые стоило бы задать в комментариях. Можно оставить отметку тревоги для модератора, чтобы он преобразовал такой ответ в комментарий. Если у автора больше 50 репутации, он уже может оставлять комментарии. В таком случае можно явно указать ему на то, что ответ должен был быть комментарием.
    - Нередко автор не справляется с форматированием. Либо его нет вообще, либо используется сырой HTML. В этом случае я обычно правлю форматирование и оставляю ссылку на [инструкцию по Markdown](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).
- (3000 реп.) [Закрытие и переоткрытие вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

  - В очередь на закрытие попадают вопросы, которые кто-либо уже отметил как потенциально подлежащие закрытию. Чаще всего либо вопрос не содержит всей необходимой информации, либо слишком обширен и субъективен. Тут всё так же, как и с первыми сообщениями - объясните автору, как улучшить вопрос или почему лучше таких вопросв не задавать. Будьте вежливы, но не потакайте новичкам и не включайте телепатию. Не стоит отвечать на оффтопичный вопрос из соображений сочувствия к автору - таким образом вы дадите положительное подкрепление его поведению и в конечном счёте нанесёте вред его профессионализму.
  - С переоткрытием всё просто. Если вопрос действительно стал лучше - голосуйте за переоткрытие. Если под вопросом есть уточняющие комментарии от других участников - можно написать им, что вопрос изменился. Пускай приходят, переоткрывают и отвечают.
- (5000 реп.) [Проверка правок в описаниях меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

  - Тут самая частая проблема - плагиат. Нередко неопытного участника осеняет гениальная мысль: можно копипастить описания меток из Википедии. Он кричит "Эврика", возлагает пальцы на кнопки Ctrl, C и V и радостно заполняет пару описаний (или пару десятков описаний). Это чревато тем, что 1) появляются описания меток, которые вообще не несут информации об использовании метки и не отвечают требованиям к описаниям; 2) в этих описаниях нередко встречаются откровенно рекламные тексты 3) нарушается лицензия на содержимое. Ладно лицензия, это можно было бы поправить ссылкой. Но такие тексты вообще никак не соответствуют тому, что должно быть в описании.

Comment: @СашаЧерных `Внесенная правка не исправила критические недочеты сообщения` - шаблонное сообщение, которое используется, когда проверяющий нажал `Отклонить и редактировать`. Лично мне в вашей правке не нравится, что вы заменили одно осмысленное и грамотно написанное слово на другое. Я бы отклонил по этой причине.

Comment: Спасибо, по первой ссылке только что перечитывал. мой вопрос в понимании пункта «Вопросы часто не содержат всей необходимой информации», подчас понять, что вопросы должны «содержать всю необходимую информацию» могут только люди, хорошо разбирающиеся в теме. Вчера, например, отклонили [следующее](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/74997) моё изменение (поправил вопрос новичка из очереди проверок), не «исправившее критические недочеты сообщения», почему счёл нужным дополнительно уточнить здесь.

Comment: _Оффтоп_. Выдирать: 1) тавтология, 2) звучит более жаргонно. В вопросе содержались другие недочёты с точки зрения русского языка («что бы» → «чтобы», лишняя и наоборот не проставленная точка).// Однако вопрос не об этом.

Comment: @СашаЧерных если вы исправляете что-то в вопросе, то не добавляйте новых ошибок и не меняйте его смысл. Вот и всё.

Comment: Вроде бы в примере не «добавил новых ошибок» и не «изменял смысл»... Да и когда заменял повторы в тексте (в совокупности с другими, более значительными изменениями) правки прежде не отклоняли.

Comment: @СашаЧерных "выдрать" и "выбрать" - это два совершенно нормальных, не жаргонных слова **с разными значениями**.

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Спасибо.

Comment: А [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/75757) я в чём неправ? Опять эти «критические недочеты сообщения». Спасибо.